# Cannot link Boost to CMake-based project on VS2015 RC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost, cmake

It gives the error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd-1_58.lib' [C:\projects\boost-http\build\algorithm.vcxproj]
```

You can see the full error at [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/vinipsmaker/boost-http/build/1.0.38/job/a4b0o5pclv49kww7#L791). The build script (`CMakeLists.txt` and how cmake is invoked) can be found on the [project repository](https://github.com/vinipsmaker/asiohttpserver/tree/travis).

I've tried a lot, but nothing seems to help. Documentation doesn't help much either. And it is weird that the same code can compile in other platforms. Help appreciated.

Comment: does the file "boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd-1_58.lib" exist in the specified linker directories?

Comment: I'll schedule another build to print the directories contents.

Comment: @m-s: You can find the [boost build contents here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/vinipsmaker/boost-http/build/1.0.39/job/l9yj6k8xfx2urhpx). There is a filed on that folder, but it is prefixed with `lib`. Maybe this is confusing CMake's `FindBoost.cmake`. What do?

Comment: Defining `BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK` at https://github.com/vinipsmaker/asiohttpserver/blob/travis/CMakeLists.txt#L73 looks incorrect since you've built Boost as static libs.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/compilation.html for further info.

Comment: @fraser, yes, it fixed the issue. If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you define `BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK` which according to the [Boost.Test docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/compilation.html) is used when consuming the dynamically-built Boost.Test lib.

Since you have built the static version, you should remove this definition.